# String.fromCharCode() does not work after the value "126"

Tags: javascript, ascii

I have been trying the following code to get the ASCII equivalent character

```
String.fromCharCode("149")
```

but, it seems to work till 126 is passed as parameter. But for 149, the symbol generated should be

> •

Comment: `String.fromCodePoint()` works for higher chars

Comment: @SanTosh, what exactly do you want? To get "•" or to understand why it doesn't work above 126?

Answer (score 2):

128 and beyond is not standard ASCII.

```
var s = "•";
alert(s.charCodeAt(0))
```

gives 8226

Comment: What has ASCII to do with this?

Comment: The question is tagged with ASCII

Comment: Yes, but methods like `charCodeAt` or `fromCharCode` handle Unicode values, not ASCII.

Comment: That's what I am answering the author -- it's not 147.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

> Getting it to work with higher values Although most common Unicode
>   values can be represented with one 16-bit number (as expected early on
>   during JavaScript standardization) and fromCharCode() can be used to
>   return a single character for the most common values (i.e., UCS-2
>   values which are the subset of UTF-16 with the most common
>   characters), in order to deal with ALL legal Unicode values (up to 21
>   bits), fromCharCode() alone is inadequate. Since the higher code point
>   characters use two (lower value) "surrogate" numbers to form a single
>   character, String.fromCodePoint() (part of the ES6 draft) can be used
>   to return such a pair and thus adequately represent these higher
>   valued characters.

Answer (score 0):

The `fromCharCode()` method converts `Unicode` values into `characters.`

to use `unicode` see the link for unicode table

http://unicode-table.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

I got `String.fromCodePoint(149)` to show inside an alert in firefox but not in IE & Chrome. It may be because of browser language settings.

But this looks correct accourding to the ASCII table. 
http://www.asciitable.com/

[image]

This is the code I used

```
alert(String.fromCodePoint(149));
```